# remove child and change css class of parent

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to remvoe img tag and change css class of span tag through jquery. and I would like to delete using ID's. I tried using this code [Delete a div or span with a id=".xxx"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124535/delete-a-div-or-span-with-a-id-xxx) but it didn't work

```
  <span id="ctl00_objContentPageTag_spzContactInformation_txt_sContactZipCode_spanImgMandatory" class="xqh_LookUpTextBox_ImgMandatory">
   <img id="ctl00_objContentPageTag_spzContactInformation_txt_sContactZipCode_imgMandatory" src="/spzBaseModule/Look_Base/Images/Admin/Icons/iconMandatory8x14.png" style="border-width:0px;align:middle;">
  </span>
```

Comment: Unrelated, but having and ID this long means you need to switch a CMS, and fast. And if it's not a CMS, then may [Cthulhu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cthulhu) mercy your soul.

Comment: @Truth It's a standard ID structure for ASP.Net Forms, each element gets 'namespaced' by any containers with IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#myid').addClass('newclass').empty();
```

[change `myid` and `newclass` to suit].

Note that this will remove *all* children of the specified span.  If you really only want to delete `IMG` tags use this instead:

```
$('#myid').addClass('newclass').children('img').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$("#ctl00_objContentPageTag_spzContactInformation_txt_sContactZipCode_spanImgMandatory").remove();
$("#ctl00_objContentPageTag_spzContactInformation_txt_sContactZipCode_imgMandatory").addClass("class_name");
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. A code block is inserted by indenting 4 spaces before any line of code. I've formatted the code for you this time, but please format it properly next time. For further help, see the [Editing FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#ctl00_objContentPageTag_spzContactInformation_txt_sContactZipCode_spanImgMandatory img").remove();
$("#ctl00_objContentPageTag_spzContactInformation_txt_sContactZipCode_spanImgMandatory").addClass("newClass");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$('#your-span-id').addClass('some-class').find('img').remove();
```